# How to calculate this integration in wolfram mathematica

Tags: wolfram-mathematica

i want to calculate this integration in mathematica , but i have faced this problem i have attached. Thanks for your assistance.

[image]

Comment: Why do you have two references to the variable of integration `du`, one of which is inside the function to be integrated?

Comment: Why are you using D as the name of a variable when D is pre-defined in Mathematica to be the function which differentiates an expression?

Comment: You could perhaps give us a TeX or printed version of the integral you want to compute so that we eliminate the problem of using correctly the Mathematica syntax.

Comment: the error mesage seems clear enough. Your expression is nonsensical.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is clearly the (du)^2 term as the following shows:
[image: Expanding the integral and evaluating each term]

But if this is really what you mean, you can do:
[image: Using parentheses to clarify the expression]

Comment: @MadPhysicist hm, during revision it very looks like a link-only answer. o.k. , the images are only per links, but I agree that in this case it is hard to make it SO-like. So I will delete my comment.

Comment: @jogo. Thanks for that. The answer was legitimately helpful, I just think the answerer either did not have the rep or did not know how to make the links show up as images.

Comment: @MadPhysicist: thanks for the help with the figures. The issue was that I don't yet have enough rep for adding figures.

Comment: @ArmindoSalvador. I figured that was it. There was no good reason to flag your answer.